# cheapest or fastest path algorithm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

i am developing path finder AngularJS application which takes 3 inputs from user From, To and search type(cheapest or fastest) and should find complete continuous path to take from a city to another given a JSON file with Data which looks like

```
 {
"currency": "EUR",
"deals": [{
    "transport": "train",
    "departure": "London",
    "arrival": "Amsterdam",
    "duration": {
        "h": "05",
        "m": "00"
    },
    "cost": 160,
    "discount": 0,
    "reference": "TLA0500"
}, {
    "transport": "bus",
    "departure": "London",
    "arrival": "Amsterdam",
    "duration": {
        "h": "07",
        "m": "45"
    },
    "cost": 40,
    "discount": 25,
    "reference": "BLA0745"
}, {
    "transport": "car",
    "departure": "London",
    "arrival": "Amsterdam",
    "duration": {
        "h": "04",
        "m": "45"
    },
    "cost": 120,
    "discount": 0,
    "reference": "CLA0445"
}, {
    "transport": "train",
    "departure": "London",
    "arrival": "Paris",
    "duration": {
        "h": "04",
        "m": "30"
    },"cost": 160,
    "discount": 0,
    "reference": "TLP0430"
}, {
    "transport": "bus",
    "departure": "London",
    "arrival": "Paris",
    "duration": {
        "h": "05",
        "m": "30"
    },
    "cost": 40,
    "discount": 50,
    "reference": "BLP0530"
}, {
    "transport": "car",
    "departure": "London",
    "arrival": "Paris",
    "duration": {
        "h": "04",
        "m": "15"
    },
    "cost": 120,
    "discount": 0,
    "reference": "CLP0415"
},...
```

the program should takes for example: from: London To: Moscow
search type: cheapest 
and gives london->paris 100$ by train
paris->Berlin 90$ by bus ... and so on till Moscow 
I was thinking of using Dijkstra algorithm but i wonder how to use it while we may have more than one option to go from a city to another which means multiple edges with different values like one for bus time and plane time!

Comment: You can use Dijkstras's algorithm with weighted edges, can't you?

Comment: i knew that with Dijkstras's algorithm we have a single weighted edge between each 2 nodes and in that case we may have mutiple edges between 2 nodes like we can go from Paris to London with bus, train or plane

Comment: Just choose the cheapest or fastest of them. The algorithm actually doesn't really change at all.

Comment: @MohamedA.Shebl did you  find the solution? do you mind if you give me the code? please, I have the same issue...